# Problem Creating MSBUILD Script

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, target, tfsbuild

I'm having trouble with the `<target>` tag in my WPF project.

What I'm trying to do is implement a post-build event in the automated team build I have set up in TFS 2010 that triggers a piece of integrated software for measuring code metrics called NDepend.  NDepend's [site](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_TFS.aspx) gives some code samples of what I need to do, I believe. These code snippets are shown below:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="NDepend"  >
    <PropertyGroup>
      <NDPath>c:\tools\NDepend\NDepend.console.exe</NDPath>
      <NDProject>$(SolutionDir)MyProject.ndproj</NDProject>
      <NDOut>$(TargetDir)NDepend</NDOut>
      <NDIn>$(TargetDir)</NDIn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec
      Command='"$(NDPath)" "$(NDProject)" /OutDir "$(NDOut)" /InDirs "$(NDIn)"'/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

and

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile" >
    <BuildStep         TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
        BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
        Message="Running NDepend analysis">
        <Output TaskParameter="Id" PropertyName="StepId" />
    </BuildStep>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <NDPath>c:\tools\NDepend\NDepend.console.exe</NDPath>
        <NDProject>$(SolutionRoot)\Main\src\MyProject.ndproj</NDProject>
        <NDOut>$(BinariesRoot)\NDepend</NDOut>
        <NDIn>$(BinariesRoot)\Release</NDIn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec 
      Command='$(NDPath) "$(NDProject)" /OutDir "$(NDOut)" /InDirs "$(NDIn)"'/>
    <BuildStep
        TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
        BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
        Id="$(StepId)"
        Status="Succeeded" />
    <OnError ExecuteTargets="MarkBuildStepAsFailed" />
</Target>

<Target Name="MarkBuildStepAsFailed">
    <BuildStep
        TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
        BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
        Id="$(StepId)"
        Status="Failed" />
</Target>
```

I run into trouble, though, when trying to find where to put this code.  The website may be telling me everything I need to know and I'm just overlooking it or something, I don't know.  But wherever I try typing in the `<target>` tags, VS just acts like it doesn't recognize it.  In fact when I try typing just about all of the tags in the above snippets VS doesn't seem to recognize it.

Am I just missing an(some) assembly reference(s) somewhere?

I've written some XAML before, but I've never seen "target" as a tag, I've always seen it in the form of a property.  So when I originally saw this code on their site, it looked a little strange to me, but I just thought it was because I haven't had a ton of exposure to XAML.

**EDIT: The above paragraph is mistaken--As seen in the comments, the aforementioned code is XML, not XAML**

The site does say that the code snippets given are for VS2008, which does make a difference, I understand.  However, I didn't realize it was THAT big of a difference.

So could it be just a difference from 2008 to 2010? In which case, what is the difference in the code from 2008 given above and what it should be in 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not WPF or XAML, it's just plain old XML.

This is a MSBuild script which typically goes in a .proj file not a .xaml file

Comment: Ahhhhh..that would explain why it looked weird and why nothing registered in VS. So would I just go into my solution, add a new item, and select "XML File" and just put the above code in there?

Comment: Open one of your existing .csproj (a csproj file is itself just a MSBuild script) files in notepad. Add the sample code from the site you posted inside the csproj file

Comment: Alternatively, you can edit the project file in Visual Studio itself if you unload the project first.

Comment: The second snippet is for Team Foundation Server's Team Build, which uses MSBuild but has its own customized structures which are being referenced in the sample.

Comment: @John Bowen, I'm trying to automatically trigger the NDepend code metrics on a team build in TFS 2010.  Sorry I didn't specify, I will edit the question to include that info.

Comment: @djacobson, I tried doing this first, but I couldn't find the csproj file in the solution tree on the right.

Comment: @AmbiguousX The .csproj file simply appears as a `Project` in Solution Explorer - it's an item with its name in **bold**, and its icon is a tiny window containing files, with a "C#" logo on it. In the tree, it's the parent of the .cs files that live within your project.

Comment: @AmbiguousX look at this link for screenshots on how to edit the project file from your solution tree http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/30/editing-project-files-resource-editors-in-vs-2010.aspx

Comment: @djacobson - oh, ok, that makes sense, thanks for your help! @qntmfred - thanks for the link! @everyone - Thank you so much for all your help! I wish I could mark all your posts as the accepted answer, but sadly I can't.  Thanks again for your help!